# Adding a header line to output of scripts in Bash (only if script generates output)

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script that calls several other scripts (syncing user lists / detecting inconsistencies). For each script that produces an output, I'd like to add a header before the actual output, but for scripts without any output, I don't want anything printed.

Currently, I simply print out the header line in any case:

```
#!/bin/bash
for scrpt in test1.sh test2.sh; do
    echo "Script $scrpt printed out:"
    ./${scrpt}
done
```

However, what I want is the "Script $script printed out:" to appear only when ./${scrpt} really produces some output.

I could store the output in a variable and check that:

```
#!/bin/bash
for scrpt in test1.sh test2.sh; do
  ctnt=`./${scrpt}`
  if [ -n "$ctnt" ]; then
    echo -e "Script returned (with temporary variable): \n$ctnt"
  fi
done
```

However, my scripts run quite some time, so I'd like the ouput to appear as soon as it is created. And before the first output is printed, the header should appear. So while the above generates the output that I need, is not a good solution for me.

What I have in mind is something that can be called like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for scrpt in test1.sh test2.sh; do
  ./${scrpt} | print-text-before-first-output "Script $scrpt printed:"
done
```

Is there such a utility available?

- I found awk 'BEGINFILE{...}', but that always executes the code, even if no output is generated. I couldn't find a corresponding BEGINOUTPUT.
- As I said, temp variables are not what I have in mind, because I'd like the output to appear as it is created.

Comment: will this help? ```./script |  awk 'FNR==1{print "This is my Header"}1'```

Comment: Only with `bash` append `| while IFS= read -r line; do if [[ $switch != "1" ]]; then printf "%s\n" "Header"; printf "%s\n" "$line"; switch="1"; else printf "%s\n" "$line"; fi; done`

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed: replace

```
./${scrpt}
```

with

```
./${scrpt} | sed '1s/^/Header\n&/'
```

Comment: The `\n` escape might not be portable to your `sed`; if it doesn't work, maybe try putting a literal newline, probably preceded by a backslash. A more portable solution is to switch to Awk or Perl.